# Setting Ajax response to drop down using json

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, struts2

Here i am using `json + ajax + struts2`  to create the dependent drop downs. First drop down having some value based on those values second dropdown are loading. In second drop down i am getting response undefined values after every click on the data of the firstdropdown (here i am using `onchange` event). I am getting the ajax response from struts2  as objects. I want to convert those objects into string for the second dropdown (it should contain id and name). I don't know how to convert objects into string. I tried some of the links in stackoverflow and googled but it doesn't work for me. Here is my code:

**Struts2:**

```
            second_drop_downList=retrieveSecond();

    ServletActionContext.getResponse().setContentType("text/html");
    PrintWriter out = ServletActionContext.getResponse().getWriter();
    out.print(second_drop_downList);
    out.flush();
```

Here i am getting the correct size how much data is present in database. I am passing those data into the ajax response through above code.

Here is my ajax code:

```
$(".country").change(function() {
        var id = $(this).val();
        var dataString = 'id=' + id;


        $.ajax({
            type : "POST",
            url : "sendDropdown.action",
            data : dataString,
            success : function(response) {
                alert(response);
            var myJSONText = JSON.stringify(response);
            //alert(myJSONText);
            var obj = JSON.parse(myJSONText);
            alert(obj);
            var html = '<option value="">select Section</option>';
            for ( var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
            html += '<option value="'+obj[i].id+'">' + obj[i].dep_name
            + '</option>';
            }
            html += '</option>';

            $('.city').html(html); 
            }
        });

    });
```

Here i am getting the response as hexadecimal format(in alert).But in dropdown i am getting undefined.

Comment: writing to response within a struts2 action, that's a very bad way of doing that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to use [Struts2 DoubleSelect](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/doubleselect.html)

Here's a good [example](http://www.mkyong.com/struts2/struts-2-sdoubleselect-example/)

If the list is really big, then it becomes a matter of choice on how you'd like the second select list.

You can use ajax of course, but the concern is, the type of data you'd like to receive.

May be you'd like to use [Struts2 Jquery Select Tag](https://code.google.com/p/struts2-jquery/wiki/SelectTag) for the second select which actually sends JSON in the response.

Or you'd like to fire an ajax request on the selection of the first select, and then get the complete second select in the response.